# Losing Data Binding When Creating Path

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Total admission that I'm only a few weeks into D3, but I've sat here for a few hours now debugging to no avail.

Notice the two `console.log(d)` statements buried in the anonymous functions. The one on the 'dummy' attribute returns the value, the one in the `d` attribute does not.

***What is different about those two?***

```
var myEdges = [
    {
        in: "934e3e11-3f9b-11e9-b2b9-c54f58764873",
        out: "936807a1-3f9b-11e9-b2b9-c54f58764873"
    },
]

svg.selectAll('path:not([elementType=temp-path])').data(myEdges)
    .enter().append('path')
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "blue")
        .style("stroke-width", "2px")
        .attr('dummy', function(d) { console.log(d); return d;})
        .attr('d', d3.linkVertical()
                                .x(function(d) { console.log(d); return d.in; })
                                .y(function(d) { return d.out; }));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not that the datum (`d`) attribute isn't being passed: it is. The problem here is just the structure of the data that the link generator is expecting.

If you look at the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#_link), you'll see that the link generator, by default, expects a data structure like this:

```
{
  source: foo,
  target: baz
}
```

By the way, you can change these properties by using `link.source()` and `link.target()`.

So, if we change your data structure, the console will work:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var myEdges = [{
  source: { in: "934e3e11-3f9b-11e9-b2b9-c54f58764873",
    out: "936807a1-3f9b-11e9-b2b9-c54f58764873"
  },
  target: { in: "934e3e11-3f9b-11e9-b2b9-c54f58764873",
    out: "936807a1-3f9b-11e9-b2b9-c54f58764873"
  }
}]

svg.selectAll('path:not([elementType=temp-path])').data(myEdges)
  .enter().append('path')
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "blue")
  .style("stroke-width", "2px")
  .attr('dummy', function(d) {
    console.log("dummy here: " + d);
    return d;
  })
  .attr('d', d3.linkVertical()
    .x(function(d) {
      console.log(d);
      return d.in;
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return d.out;
    }));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Finally, these other answers may help you to understand the data structure required by the link generator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44760465/5768908 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/51424331/5768908

Comment: YES! Damn... that one got me. So, it's really saying `d.source` is what's undefined? Wish that was a bit clearer in the docs or error messaging. Thank you.

Comment: @Scott Yes, you are right, the docs are a bit cryptic sometimes.

Comment: So, I'd rather not change the structure of my data for other reasons, but is there a place I can transform the data as input to this attr?

Comment: @Scott I'm not following your question above: to draw the path you need to have **two** object properties, one for the source and one for the target, and in each one you need to have two values, one for x and one for y (have a look at the other answers linked at the end of my answer to see how the data should be). I believe it's better if you post a **new** question, with the data structure you have and the visual outcome you're expecting.